# How to go deeper with Eloquent hasMany in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I'm trying to get a sort of results collection out from the db, still taking advantage of Eloquent.

I have a table called as_inspections, a table called as_green_areas and a table called as_assets

Each Inspection has a single green area, and each green area has many assets.

When I fetch the inspections I do something like this:

## Inspection model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inspection extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'as_inspections';

    public function greenAreas()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\GreenArea', 'id');
    }
}
```

## GreenArea model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GreenArea extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'as_green_areas';
}
```

## Routes

```
Route::get('inspections', ['middleware' => 'cors', function()
{
    $isp = new \App\Inspection();
    return $isp
        ->with('greenAreas')
        ->get();
}]);
```

Now I'd like to do something like this:

```
Route::get('inspections', ['middleware' => 'cors', function()
    {
        $isp = new \App\Inspection();
        return $isp
            ->with('greenAreas')
            ->with('assets') // where each green area has its own set of assets
            ->get();
    }]);
```

As written in the comment, I'd like to get all the assets for that green area, and then all the green areas for that inspection.

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firs of all your model class and relationship will be defined like this, make sure to replace the foreign keys in the relationship function with correct one in your table,

```
namespace App;    //model class for inspection

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inspection extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'as_inspections';

    public function greenArea()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\GreenArea', 'greenareaid','id');
    }
}


namespace App;   //model for green area

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GreenArea extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'as_green_areas';

    public function inspection()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Inspection', 'greenareaid','id');
    }

     public function assets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Asset', 'greenareaid','id');
    }
}

namespace App;   //model for asset

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Asset extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'as_assets';
     public function greenArea()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\GreenArea', 'greenareaid','id');
    }

}
```

then you can use eager loading of eloquent to easily bring the related models as in the example bellow.. you pass the primary key of the inspection model to find method, and then grab green area and related asset for it

```
Inspection:find(1)->with('greenArea.assets');
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for this answer! I'm currently trying to implement it. Just one question. Are  greenareaid, inspectionid the foreign keys? In the as_inspections table I have a fk called green_area_fk, should I swap inspectionid with green_area_fk or leave id as is the primary key for the inspections table? I'm quite confused about the optional parameters for these methods...

Comment: It worked! Thanks! If you have time to link me some resources to learn more about the optional parameters of the eloquent methods like hasMany and so on it will be amazing!

Comment: see my updated code above, I have simple changed the belongsTo method, in your case you can term it like, you have one inspection for a green area, as you keep foreign key in inspection table, so always note that belongsTo relationship is defined where your foreign key reside ...

best tutorial is Laravel.com, documentation , I have been referring to it since more than 1 year and completed an ERP system ....

Comment: Now it makes a lot more sense! Thanks! Now I understand that greenareaid is the foreign key inside the inspections table and id is the primary key for the green_areas table! Right?

Comment: yes, you are correct, as its 1 - 1 relations, you can define other way too, place the inpectionid in greenarea table, either choice has no different, its depends on the situation you have to place in the appropriate table

Comment: Again, thanks a lot. For the example and for the explain!

Comment: you are welcome and don't forget to vote my answer as I am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
Inspection::find($id)->greenAreas()->assets()->all();
```

This will fetch all the assets of the greenAreas, inspected by Inspection $id.

I'm not sure which query you're looking for.

Comment: It's an AJAX request, the mobile app requires to the API a set of informations about the inspections. And it's not passing any ID. So I need to get ALL the inspections, and for each inspection the the green_areas related, and for each green_area ALL the assets. I don't even know how to google this :/

Comment: `Inspection::all()->with('greenArea.assets');` Should work

Comment: Inspection::find($id)->greenAreas()->first(), this is not correct, you donot need to call first() when the relationship is defined as hasone,